# Particle on a sphere, it's solution having extra $(-1)^m$ term

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, schroedinger-equation, conventions, spherical-harmonics

To solve a particle on a sphere problem in quantum mechanics we get the below equation :$\left[\frac{1}{\sin \theta} \frac{d}{d \theta}\left(\sin \theta \frac{d}{d \theta}\right)-\frac{m^{2}}{\sin ^{2} \theta}\right] \Theta(\theta)=-A \Theta(\theta) .$

To solve this differential equation, we start with a change of independent variable $z=\cos \theta$, where $z$ is the rectangular coordinate for the particle, assuming a unit sphere. We also introduce a new function
$$
P(z)=\Theta(\theta) .
$$
Using this substitution we've this equation
$\left(\left(1-z^{2}\right) \frac{d^{2}}{d z^{2}}-2 z \frac{d}{d z}+A-\frac{m^{2}}{\left(1-z^{2}\right)}\right) P(z)=0 .$ whose solutions are the associated Legendre polynomials :

$$
P_{\ell}^{-m}(z)=P_{\ell}^{m}(z)
$$

To get back the angular solution I should use $
P(z)=\Theta(\theta)$ and also normalise it, giving me

$\Theta_{\ell}^{m}(\theta)= \frac{(2 \ell+1)}{2} \frac{(\ell-m) !}{(\ell+m) !} P_{\ell}^{m}(\cos \theta) .$

But my book writes the solution with an additional $(-1)^{m}$ term as
$\Theta_{\ell}^{m}(\theta)= (-1)^{m}\frac{(2 \ell+1)}{2} \frac{(\ell-m) !}{(\ell+m) !} P_{\ell}^{m}(\cos \theta) .$

Why is that so?

Comment: It's just a normalization for the wave-function. You can choose it anyway you like.

Comment: If $\Theta(\theta)$ is a solution, then $-\Theta(\theta)$ is also a solution.